# Generating React/Express Routes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, express, react-router

Currently I have a number of routes that follow formulas like so:

```
items/:item?
```

Is there a library that will allow me to do something like so:

```
generateUrl('items/:item?', { item : '1' }) = 'items/1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer, the package react-router contains a function here that does the job: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/generatePath.js#L23

So to generate my own routes I have to do the following:

`import { generatePath } from "react-router";
generatePath('/items/:item?', { item: itemID });`

Make sure you also install the `path-to-regexp` module.